# Is there a way to pass a closure to UIAlertAction that will return a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, handler, uialertaction

I'm trying to get more into the Swift Closure concept and I have this problem, I have the following UIAlertController method:

```
 public static func showSerialNumberAlertController(handler: @escaping (UIAlertAction) -> String?) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Serial Number", message: "Please enter your serial number", preferredStyle: .alert)

    // ADD ACTIONS HANDLER
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
    cancelAction.isEnabled = true
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let continueAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default) { (_) in
        let serialNumberField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        let text = serialNumberField.text
        print("Serial number entered: \(text!)")
    }
    continueAction.isEnabled = false
    alertController.addAction(continueAction)

    // ADD TEXT FIELDS
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Serial number"
        // enable continue button when serial not empty
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange, object: textField, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            continueAction.isEnabled = textField.text != "" && textField.text?.count as! Int > 3
        }
    }

    alertController.view.tintColor = Colors.mainColor
    getRootViewController()?.present(alertController, animated: true)
}
```

now what I'm trying to do is to replace the handler of the `continueAction` `UIAlertAction` with a handler I receive from outside which will extract the text from the serial number `UITextField` when the user presses the continue button and pass it as the returned value.

So I have this method outside of this scope in another file, from which I'm calling this static method:

```
public func getSerialFromAlert(alertController: UIAlertController) -> String? 
{
    let serialNumberField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
    let text = serialNumberField.text
    print("Serial number entered: \(text!)")
    return text
}
```

I want to pass this method as a handler but when I do that I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(UIAlertAction) -> String?' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'

**So the question is:** Is it possible to achieve this and pass a handler that will return a value as a parameter? If so what would be the right way to do this? If not, what would be the alternative for an `UIAlertController` action delegate that has to access alert views in order to extract data?

Comment: Under what class are you writing showSerialNumberAlertController?  And under what class are you calling getSerialFromAlert?

Comment: @ElTomato, showSerialNumberAlertController is written under Utils class, while getSerialFromAlert is under MainViewController I want to call showSerialNumberAlertController from MainViewController and pass getSerialFromAlert as a parameter that will return me a value when continue button is pressed.

Comment: Then what you should do is to include a view controller in the showSerialNumberAlertController function as an argument.

Comment: You say "a closure to UIAlertAction that will return a String."  But you don't have a string in your escape clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you could change your method signature to

```
showSerialNumberAlertController(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void)
```

and within this function change the continue action to:

```
let continueAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default) { (_) in
    let serialNumberField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
    let text = serialNumberField.text
    completion(text ?? "")
}
```

Finally you call the method like this:

```
UIAlertController.showSerialNumberAlertController { serial in
    print("Serial number entered: \(serial)")
}
```

Comment: what "completion(text ?? "")" means? because I'm getting "Use of unresolved identifier 'completion'" error for this line?

Comment: `serialNumberField.text` returns an optional. So `text` could possibly be `nil`. This line means that the `completion` handler either returns the serial number (if not `nil`) or an empty string. Your problem has to be somewhere else. Did you make all three changes in your code?

Comment: Side note: typecasting seems to be redundant here, you could just use `let text = alertController.textFields?[0].text` instead.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I didn't commit all the changes you made. Now it works, thank you very much for you help.